# Covariance function for inhomogeneous poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, estimation, poisson-process

If we have an inhomogeneous Poisson process with intensity $\lambda(t)$, what does the covariance function $\mathbb{E}[X_s, X_t]$ look like? Can anyone point me to a derivation?

I would like to ask the same question for a Hawkes type process, where the intensity can be "level-dependent".

If these question have a complicated answer, what I am really interested in is that I have an entire covariance matrix $\Sigma(t, s)$ for a set of discrete $t$ and $s$ and I would like to use it to estimate $\lambda(t)$.

Thank you!

Comment: And your take on this would be?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what take means?

Comment: It means:  Please show how much you understand and exactly where you are having trouble.  What are your attempts, thoughts, and ideas?  People don't like solving other's problems from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an inhomogeneous Poisson process with intensity $\lambda(t)$, $X(t)$ (representing the number of occurrences in the interval $[0, t]$) is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\Lambda(t) = \int_0^x \lambda(x)\; dx$.  The covariance is $\text{Cov}(X_s, X_t)$.  But
the numbers of occurrences in disjoint intervals are independent.
Thus if $s \le t$, $X(s)$ and $X(t) - X(s)$ are independent, and

$$\text{Cov}(X(s), X(t)) = \text{Cov}(X(s), X(s))  + \text{Cov}(X(s),X(t) - X(s)) = \text{Cov}(X(s),X(s)) = \text{Var}(X(s)) = \Lambda(s)$$